# COM Access Violation in visual studio 2010 package on UIShell::ShowContext

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, com, vspackage

I'm rather stuck with a problem I found while attempting to port a package from visual studio 2008 to 2010 and wondered if anyone would have any ideas please note this *worked* in visual studio 2008 and I am unsure why it doesn't work in 2010,

the offending piece of code is here:

```
IVsUIShell uiShell = (IVsUIShell)TestPackage.GetGlobalService(typeof (SVsUIShell));
Guid context =  GuidList.GUIDTestMarkerCmdSet;
                POINTS[] menuPos = new POINTS[1];
                menuPos[0].x = (short)Cursor.Position.X;
                menuPos[0].y = (short)Cursor.Position.Y;
                var hr = uiShell.ShowContextMenu(0, ref context,(int)PkgCmdIDList.ContextMenu, menuPos, this); //access violation happens here.
                if (hr != VSConstants.S_OK)
                    return VSConstants.S_FALSE;
                break;
```

uiShell context is a vaild com pointer as far as I can tell and I can call other methods on it without it blowing up.

I think It has to do with the context menu setup in the xml vsct file. relevent parts of which can be seen below.

```
<Groups>
  <Group guid="guidTestMarkerCmdSet" id="ContextGroup" priority="0x100" >
    <Parent guid="guidTestMarkerCmdSet" id="ContextMenu"/>
  </Group>
</Groups>

<Menus>
  <Menu guid="guidTestMarkerCmdSet" id="ContextMenu" type="Context">
    <Parent guid="guidTestMarkerCmdSet" id="0"/>
    <Strings>
      <ButtonText>Test Runner Context Menu</ButtonText>
      <CommandName>TestRunnerContextMenu</CommandName>
    </Strings>
  </Menu>
</Menus> 

<Buttons>
      <Button guid="guidTestMarkerCmdSet" id="cmdRunTest" priority="0x1" type="Button">
    <Parent guid="guidTestMarkerCmdSet" id="ContextGroup"/>
    <Strings>
      <ButtonText>Run Test</ButtonText>
      <CommandName>cmdRunTest</CommandName>
    </Strings>
  </Button>

  <Button guid="guidTestMarkerCmdSet" id="cmdDebugTest" priority="0x1" type="Button">
    <Parent guid="guidTestMarkerCmdSet" id="ContextGroup"/>
    <Strings>
      <ButtonText>Debug Test</ButtonText>
      <CommandName>cmdDebugTest</CommandName>
    </Strings>
  </Button>
```

any help would be much appeciated, I'm rather mythed atm

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug was caused by me using an button of type "MenuButton" in the vsct which is now not supported in vs2010.

the workaround is to use a menu inside the group of the context menu instead.